# Mysql three table join with aggregate columns and group by

Tags: mysql

I have three tables of data with foreign key relationship but when i do a query its giving error like as `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #22 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column invoices.imported'`

Below is my tables structure

```
jobs

id      invoice_no      customer_id
1       H045                1
2       A041                2

job_detials 

id      job_id      est_start_date      est_off_date    
1         1           04-01-2017        01-01-2017
2         1           05-02-2017        03-06-2017
3         1           01-05-2017        17-04-2017
4         2           14-04-2017        15-02-2017
5         2           12-04-2017        03-04-2017   

invoices

id      job_id      imported
1       1               1
2       2               0
```

And the query which i m trying to execute the results.

```
select `jobs`.`id` as `job_id`, `invoices`.`imported`,
MIN(job_details.est_start_date) as est_start_date, MAX(job_details.est_off_date) as est_off_date, `jobs`.`invoice_no` from `jobs`
left join `job_details` on `job_details`.`job_id`= `jobs`.`id` left join `invoices` on `invoices`.`job_id` = `jobs`.`id`
group by `jobs`.`id`
```

Can some body help me out to solve this error. ? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many SQL databases, you must `GROUP BY` all non-aggregated fields; in this case, you need to group by `job_id`, `imported`, and `invoice_no`.

Under certain configurations MySQL does allow you to omit such fields, but the more recent defaults tend toward restricting such syntax since selecting something such as `invoices`.`imported`, that is not a part of a table whose primary key was grouped on, without grouping on it can have non-deterministic results.

Comment: Ninja'd by about 5 seconds.

Comment: @Uueerdo : Okay will try to  group  by those columns

Comment: @Uueerdo : Thank you for the information . it worked !